# React component printed twice on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

My React component named 'Person' prints twice on the screen,once without props & once with props.

```js
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>Hello I am Arjun</h1>
          <Person>But What's The Language?</Person>
          <Person technology="React" syntax="JSX"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
//Person.js

import React from 'react'

const person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <p>The technology used is {props.technology} & the syntax 
            is {props.syntax}</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default person
```

And this is the output :

[image: React Output]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: because you're printing it twice?  `<Person>But What's The Language?</Person>
          <Person technology="React" syntax="JSX"/>`

Comment: This is so normal since you are rendering Person component twice. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: There are 3 lines in the output.I only want 2 lines ie. "But what's the language?" and "The technology used is React & syntax is JSX".Why is the second line present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you in fact render your component twice. You should have only one `<Person />` Tag in your `App` component:

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>Hello I am Arjun</h1>
          <Person technology="React" syntax="JSX">But What's The Language?</Person>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.Really appreciate it.It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers show you how you should do that and told the main reason. I will try to explain it a little bit more. You are rendering your component twice and you have three lines because of the structure of your component.

First render:

```
<Person>But What's The Language?</Person>
```

Here you are rendering the component with a child. Your child here is "But What's The Language?" string. You don't pass any other prop other then child. Your component shape is:

```
<p>{props.children}</p>
<p>The technology used is {props.technology} & the syntax is {props.syntax}</p>
```

First line is coming from the children prop. Second line is your paragraph with other props. So, in the first render you don't have those props, hence rendering as empty for `technology` and `syntax`.

Your second render:

```
<Person technology="React" syntax="JSX"/>
```

Here you don't have any child. It means no `<Person>Child</Person>` shape but just `<Person />` For this render you have other props. Third line is coming from this render with `technology` and `syntax` props. Hence you don't have any children prop, first line is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I believed that the number of times a component is printed depends only on the number of times it is called.Now it is clear that it also depends on the number of times a component is rendered.

Comment: Yes, you can render a component as many times as you want. Actually, this is how you handle the render for lots of items (ie, coming from an array). But you don't do this manually, you do this generally mapping the array and rendering the items.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering your component twice, to obtain the desired output you could do something like this:

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello I am Arjun</h1>
        <Person technology="React" syntax="JSX">
          But What's The Language?
        </Person>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

that way, your component renders its children "But What's The Language?", and receives the `technology` and `syntax` properties for the second line.

Comment: Yep I understood now.Actually I just started learning React but never really understood the concept of component rendering until I faced this problem.Also thanks to @devserkan for making the concept clear.